# REST API: retrieving a report with more than 2000 rows

Tags: api, reporting, rest

We are working with the Salesforce REST API to fetch reports.

When fetching more than 2000 records from a report how does the pagination work? Is there any querystring parameter to append to the URL so we can access the next page(s) of users?

This is what the URL looks like.

```
$url = "{$instance_url}/services/data/v42.0/analytics/reports/00xxxxxxxxxxA5";
```

If possible, we would like not to use SQL queries, but directly the `analytics/reports` endpoint.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! A couple of possible answers: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/242103/81648 | https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/226973/81648

Comment: @Moonpie Thanks for that -- but is there any way to get pagination working on the  `analytics/reports` endpoint?

Comment: I have no experience so can't say directly. But the accepted answer to the second question I linked to addresses `analytics/reports`. Is that an approach that you can use?

Comment: @Moonpie I think even on the second question they still suggest using SOQL, if I am not wrong. In the docs I couldn't find anything about the pagination in the `analytics/reports` endpoint.

Comment: Out of the box - no, [you have do it yourself](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22631/workaround-for-offset-2000-limit-on-soql-query) with a filter by ordering (sorting) the report on whatever unique field such as a record ID.  Vote for this idea: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gda98UAB/increase-the-analytics-rest-api-limit-of-2000-report-rows

Comment: @identigral : Please put that as an answer!