# Can report instance list API results be paginated?

Tags: rest-api, pagination

I am querying the following API endpoint:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_instances_resource.htm

The documentation makes no mention of pagination, for example the `"nextRecordsUrl"` key, as can be present when querying Contacts for an Account via SOQL query (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm)

I find the documentation very hard to search, but does anyone know if endpoint response can possibly be paginated, e.g. if there are > 2000 report instances?

If you could point me in the direction of some documentation, I would be grateful.

Comment: If this was a report, then see our comment https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/384383/rest-api-retrieving-a-report-with-more-than-2000-rows . For instances of a report, do you really have more than 2000 running instances of a single report?

Comment: Yeah, extremely unlikely, but I'm trying to write library code that will handle multiple endpoints.